# Multi-Line Labeling Positioning

Tags: qgis, labeling

After hours and hours of reading I was finally able to get multi-line labels established on my current project. I'm using QGIS 3.16.2 and I'm trying to get multi-line labels positioned at different positions around an item. As you can see in the image below these are a few of the labels I want to use and I'd like for them to be at different positions around the well symbol. For example the long string of numbers I want posted above, for the operator name (second label) I want it to the right of the symbol, the well name (third label) below the symbol, and lastly the well number (fourth label) to be to the left of the symbol.

I've read and read and I can't seem to find anywhere where this has been discussed or solved.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If the attributes are stored in separated fields:

Create a rule based label and setup four of them:

[image]

Go to placement for each of them and choose "Offset from point". Choose half the size of the symbol (in my example a dot of size 10 = offset of 5) as offset and the quadrant you wish to place it on:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Also you can watch videos about labelling in Klas Karlsson's YouTube channel.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySYmZv7HQiY    Complex Labels
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWr85Oe0Yg0   All about labelling

Comment: Wow...I made something super easy ridiculously complicated, story of my life!