# QGIS place label on both sides of the item

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have assigned multiple of labels for my items. Following the threads here

https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2017/05/create-labels-from-multi-columns-in-qgis.html
https://anitagraser.com/2011/06/15/multi-line-labels-in-qgis/

or here

[How to create vertical labels in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45365/how-to-create-vertical-labels-in-qgis)

but I couldn't find how to place them on both sides of my object.

Since I have 2 breaks, it looks quite troublesome.

I tried to do something in the Placement section, but I don't know what should change there.

How can I place these labels on both sides of my object?

[image]

Comment: You can do it using rule based labels like here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389737/multi-line-labeling-positioning/389742#389742 Only adjust your placement rules.

Comment: Did you try clicking `On line` (see you screenshot)? Or how do you imagine the label to be: you want it have to be repeated on both sides of the road? Or just one line on the left, the second on and the third on the right side of the line?